# how do I make `std::find_if` give all the matches, something like greedy matching in a regular expression?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to filter all the values that are greater than 3. here is my working code

```
void ForEach(const std::vector<int> &values, void (*fun_ptr)(int))
{
    for (int v : values)
        if (v > 3)
            fun_ptr(v);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values = {1, 5, 6, 2, 3};

    auto lambd = [](int v)
    { printf("%d ", v); };

    ForEach(values, lambd);

    return 0;
}
```

the code above yields `5 6`, which is as expected.

however, the following code just gives the first one, that is, `5`

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values = {1, 5, 6, 2, 3};
    auto it = std::find_if(values.begin(), values.end(), [](int v){return v>3;});
    printf("%d ", *it);

    return 0;
}
```

how do I make it give all the matches, something like greedy matching in a regular expression?

Comment: find_if will only ever find one item. You will have to make a view on your current data. Like [std::filter_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view)

Comment: Call `find_if` in a loop, updating the "begin" iterator each time you find a match.

Comment: Or if possible use the [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) library.

Comment: It strikes me that [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) may be of use here.

Comment: Actually, depending on your use-case, why not a simple [range `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) over the whole vector, an explicit `if (current_val_in_loop == value_looking_for)` and then doing what you need to do with the element?

Comment: @PepijnKramer But keep in mind that standard views are [completely broken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv29fo9sUjY).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> filter all the values that are greater than 3

That sounds like the perfect job for a C++20 `filter_view`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>    // misc. views
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> values = {1, 5, 6, 2, 3};
    for (int value : values | std::views::filter([](int v) { return v > 3; })) {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5
6
```

... or `std::ranges::copy_if` and a `std::ostream_iterator<int>`:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> values = {1, 5, 6, 2, 3};
    std::ranges::copy_if(values, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"),
                         ([](int v) { return v > 3; }));
}
```

---

If you use a pre C++20 compiler and want to use `std::find_if`:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> values = {1, 5, 6, 2, 3};

    for (auto it = values.begin(); ; ++it) {
        it = std::find_if(it, values.end(), [](int x) { return x > 3; });
        if (it == values.end())
            break;
        std::printf("%d\n", *it);
    }
}
```

Which could be simplified with `std::copy_if`:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> values = {1, 5, 6, 2, 3};

    std::copy_if(values.begin(), values.end(),
                 std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"),
                 [](int x) { return x > 3; });
}
```

Comment: Actually, the `if` could be omitted. Anyway, you're my hero ~~

Comment: @singularli Thanks for pointing that out. It was a late night yesterday :-) ... and you're welcome! Glad it helped!

Comment: The pre-C++20 version honestly doesn't simplify anything, and I don't think anyone would prefer that style. Maybe it's worth mentioning how to process the vector with `std::remove_if` or `std::copy_if`.

Comment: In the second code snippet I'd prefer to [rephrase the loop](https://godbolt.org/z/jE6z1GGes) to avoid `std::find_if()` repetition.

Comment: @JanSchultke The pre C++20 version may not simplify it, but it does give an answer to _"how do I make `std::find_if` give all the matches...?"_. I added a `std::copy_if` option. I don't think `remove_if` would be great in this sitiuation.

Comment: @Evg That's certainly an option (and looks nice). I replaced my original with your version.

Comment: One important difference between `std::find_if` and `std::views::filter` is that with `std::views::filter` one is [not allowed](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.filter#iterator-1) to modify elements that satisfy the predicate with values that don't satisfy it: *Modification of the element a `filter_view​::​iterator` denotes is permitted, but results in undefined behavior if the resulting value does not satisfy the filter predicate.*

Answer (score 2):

I like the method with views/ranges (btw, Boost offers them, too), but this problem can be approached in multiple ways, depending what you actually want using e.g. `copy_if`:

```cpp
    std::copy_if(
        std::begin(v),
        std::end(v),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, "\n"}, 
        [] (auto x){return x>3;});
```

Note that if your intent is just a printout, `ostream_iterator` can be utlized.
Another ways involve `filter_iterator` from Boost

```cpp
template<typename Filter>
static void fil_it(const std::vector<int>& vec, Filter f)
{
    std::cout << "filter iterator + copy\n";
    auto start{boost::make_filter_iterator(f, std::begin(vec), std::end(vec))};
    auto finish{boost::make_filter_iterator(f, std::end(vec), std::end(vec))};
    std::copy(
        start,
        finish,
        std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, "\n"});

    std::cout << "filter iterator + for loop\n";
    for(; start != finish; ++start){
        std::cout << *start << '\n';
    }
}
```

...or usage of `boost::adaptors`, in a similar manner to C++20 views:

```cpp
template<typename Filter>
static void fil_rng(const std::vector<int>& vec, Filter f)
{

    auto rng{boost::adaptors::filter(vec, f)};
    std::cout << "range adaptor + copy\n";

    std::copy(
        std::begin(rng),
        std::end(rng),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, "\n"});
    for (auto x : rng) {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
}
```

Live demo:
https://godbolt.org/z/KMefE48nW